# Laravel valet not working not resolve

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

i have a problem with Valet.

i'm checked the `port 80 (netstat and lsof -i :80)`

then "`valet install`"

```
user@MacBook:~$ valet install 
Stopping nginx.... 
Installing nginx configuration... 
Installing nginx directory... 
Updating PHP configuration... 
Restarting php71... 
Restarting dnsmasq... 
Restarting nginx...
```

**Valet installed successfully!**

then i try `user@MacBook:~$ ping foobar.dev ^C`

but this domain was not pinged

i tried anything: reinstall valet, nginx, valet link, valet park etc.... but domain was not resolved help me please

Comment: What is the output of `lsof -i tcp -c nginx -a`

Comment: before starting valet - nothing, but after "valet install"                                             nginx   12478 alexander    6u  IPv4 0x97c3522f574c0abb      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12479 alexander    6u  IPv4 0x97c3522f574c0abb      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12480 alexander    6u  IPv4 0x97c3522f574c0abb      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12481 alexander    6u  IPv4 0x97c3522f574c0abb      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

Comment: You also need to use `valet link foobar`. See this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet

Comment: In this man, u can see that all domain *.dev must be pinged

Comment: then i try valet link and valet park but it's not work again

Comment: See if these helps https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/329 and https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/299

Answer (score 0):

First, you should link your website:

1. Go to your project directory.
2. Run the command `valet link {project_name}` to link your project.
3. The local domain will be created as `.test` domain like "foobar.test"
4. Go to your `hosts` file and add your project domain to it, it can be found in `/etc/hosts`:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 foobar.test
   ```

Please note that the `.dev` domains are no longer valid for Chrome, checkout this link [Use a .dev domain? Not anymore](https://medium.engineering/use-a-dev-domain-not-anymore-95219778e6fd)